# mutate(foo = bar + bla) but sometimes bar or bla don't exist which results in error message

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a data frame that usually looks like this:

```
structure(list(date = structure(18780, class = "Date"), bar = 1L, 
    Sessions = 2990L, `bla` = 20L), row.names = c(NA, 
-1L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like:

```
    # A tibble: 1 x 4
  date         bar Sessions   bla
  <date>     <int>    <int> <int>
1 2021-06-02     1     2990    20
```

With this I mutate:

```
mydf %>% mutate(foo = bar + bla)
# A tibble: 1 x 5
  date         bar Sessions   bla   foo
  <date>     <int>    <int> <int> <int>
1 2021-06-02     1     2990    20    21
```

But, this is within the context of a shiny app with user filters. Sometimes, the resulting data frame after user inputs there's a dataframe with no bar or bla field. So when I add them during mutate I get

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `foo`.
x object 'bar' not found
ℹ Input `foo` is ``bar` + `bla``
```

In the case where either bar or bla doesn't exist, I'd still like the sum of the remaining one in my mutate. Else just create the new feature foo but give it a value of 0. In R english something like:

```
mydf %>% mutate(foo = if(bar exists then bar else 0) + if(bla exists then bla else 0))
```

Is there a 'nice' or elegant way of doing this? Perhaps tidyverse approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps, this might help using `any_of` -

```
library(dplyr)
cols <- c('bar', 'bla')

df %>%  mutate(foo = rowSums(select(., any_of(cols))))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
#  date         bar Sessions   bla   foo
#  <date>     <int>    <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 2021-06-02     1     2990    20    21
```

If `bar` is absent this will still work -

```
df %>%  
  select(-bar) %>%
  mutate(foo = rowSums(select(., any_of(cols))))

#  date       Sessions   bla   foo
#  <date>        <int> <int> <dbl>
#1 2021-06-02     2990    20    20
```

Comment: Beautiful, yes it works thanks a lot, accepting when the time comes off! Bonus, anyway to use 'tidyselect', if that's the right phrase? I.e. instead of having to use string quoted variable names within any_of?

Comment: That would require a different approach I think because `any_of` works only with character variables.

Comment: An alternative that gives the same result is `mydf %>% mutate(foo = sum(c_across(any_of(c("bar", "bla")))))`.

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way using apply function

```
library(dplyr)
mydf %>%
  mutate(foo =apply(select(.,"bar","bla"), 1, sum))

# A tibble: 1 x 5
  date         bar Sessions   bla   foo
  <date>     <int>    <int> <int> <int>
1 2021-06-02     1     2990    20    21
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `tidyverse` methods

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     select(-bar) %>% 
     mutate(foo = select(cur_data(), any_of(cols)) %>%
          coalesce(., tibble(!! cols[1] := 0)) %>%
          reduce(`+`))
# A tibble: 1 x 4
#  date       Sessions   bla   foo
#  <date>        <int> <int> <int>
#1 2021-06-02     2990    20    20
```

---

If both columns are not present

```
df1 %>%
     select(-all_of(cols)) %>% 
     mutate(foo = select(cur_data(), any_of(cols)) %>%
          coalesce(., tibble(!! cols[1] := 0)) %>%
          reduce(`+`))
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  date       Sessions   foo
  <date>        <int> <dbl>
1 2021-06-02     2990     0
```

Comment: I like this syntax. WOuld this return 0 if both 'bar' and 'bla' were missing?

Comment: @DougFir thanks. you may do `df1 %>% select(-all_of(cols)) %>%  mutate(foo = select(cur_data(), any_of(cols)) %>% {if(ncol(.) > 0) reduce(., `+`) else 0})`

Comment: @DougFir Also, from the comments, you may use `df1 %>% select(-all_of(cols)) %>% rowwise %>% mutate(foo = sum(c_across(any_of(c("bar", "bla")))))`.  In that comment, `rowwise` was not specified.  For a single row dataset that comment works

Comment: @DougFir I updated with a much more compact method.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the answer akrun!

Answer (score 1):

I created this function in a package of mine to do just what you described at the end. It adds in a column to the data set with a certain value - but only if it is missing.

```r
add_missing_column <- function(.data, ..., .before = NULL, .after = NULL, .name_repair = c("check_unique", "unique", "universal", "minimal")) {
  .dots <- rlang::enquos(...)
  
  cols_to_add <- .dots[!names(.dots) %in% names(.data)]
  tibble::add_column(.data, !!!cols_to_add, .before = .before, .after = .after, .name_repair = .name_repair)
}
```

So in this case I would do something like this.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  add_missing_column(bar = 0L,
                     bla = 0L) %>% 
  mutate(foo = bar + bla)
```

Or more often, I set the columns in a list.

```r
missing_cols <- list(bar = 0L, bla = 0L)

df %>% 
  add_missing_column(!!!missing_cols) %>% 
  mutate(foo = bar + bla)
```

You can set the default to anything you want, since it just forwards to `add_column()`.